# 2012 MQRC_ENVIRONMENT_ERROR using MQ Classes for .Net & SSL

Tags: .net, ssl, ibm-mq

Using .NET 4.7.2, IBM WebSphere MQ Classes for .Net version 7.0.1.13 (amqmdnet.dll), and a DigiCert SSL, the last line of the following code issues
error 2012 "MQRC_ENVIRONMENT_ERROR" when attempting to connect to a remote MQ queue manager. I have verified the queue manager name, the CIPHER_SPEC, port, etc.

```
            var properties = new Hashtable
            {
                { MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED },
                { MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, "hostname.com" },
                { MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, "1417" },
                { MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, "12345678_SND.C1" },
                { MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY, "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256" },
                { MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, "C:\\Temp\\my-ssl.pfx" }
            };

            var queueManager = new MQQueueManager("QM", properties);
```

I believe I am at least connecting with the queue manager enough for it to issue an SSL error both when I don't specify an SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY:

> Remote CipherSpec error for channel '12345678_SND.C1'.   The remote
> end of channel '12345678_SND.C1' has had a CipherSpec error. The
> channel did not start.   Review the error logs on the remote system to
> discover the problem with the CipherSpec.

... and when I do specify an SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY but not an SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY:

> The path and stem name for the SSL key repository have not been
> specified.   The directory path and file stem name for the SSL key
> repository have not been specified. On a MQ client system there is no
> default location for this file. SSL connectivity is therefore
> impossible as this file cannot be accessed.      Use the MQSSLKEYR
> environment variable or MQCONNX API call to specify the directory path
> and file stem name for the SSL key repository.

Am I wrong in assuming these errors are coming from the queue manager? If that's the case I believe I'm dealing with strictly an SSL error (wrong format, needs password, etc.). Any MQ from .Net help greatly appreciated!

Comment: `MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, "C:\\Temp\\my-ssl.pfx"` is not valid, for `MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED` you need to import the cert to the windows user or machine key store and specify that value as `*USER` or `*SYSTEM`.  V7.0 has been out of support since 2015.  You would be better off getting a later version published by IBM to Nuget, 9.3 is the latest version.

Comment: How will it know *which* certificate to use if I use *USER? I assume that's the certs in "Personal"?

Comment: By default the friendly name it looks for is ibmwebspheremqlowercaseusername, but you can specify a certlabel to be any value as long as it matches the friendly name in the key store.

Comment: Gotcha looks like I specify a friendly name by adding property "{ MQC.CERT_LABEL_PROPERTY, "cert-friendly-name" }" to the hashtable? I'm now using 9.3.2.1 and there was no definition for SSL_CERT_LABEL_PROPERTY.

I've also seen where you change the SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY property to a format like "CurrentUser\\My\\<CertificateThumbprint_OR_Subject>"

Comment: I have not seen `SSL_CERT_LABEL_PROPERTY` before or the format you show referencing the cert label as part of the `SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY`.

Comment: How would I "specify a cert label" then, so it knows which cert to use? Say, if my cert's Friendly Name = "mike123"?


```but you can specify a certlabel to be any value as long as it matches the friendly name in the key store```

Comment: `MQC.CERT_LABEL_PROPERTY` sounds right to me.   Did this work?

Comment: Yes, it got further! Got to the MQ server & logged a cipher mismatch error. Even though I'm specifying TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, it complains about using TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA & I have no idea where it would get that from.

```The CipherSpec required in the local channel definition is
'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256'. The name of the CipherSpec negotiated during
the SSL handshake is 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA'. A code is displayed if the
name of the negotiated CipherSpec cannot be determined.```

Comment: Manged .NET can only specify a cipher to be matched against to determine the TLS version to use.   In this case the queue manger you are connecting to must be v9.1 or lower.   At 9.2 you can specify a "ANY" CIPHER on the SVRCONN.   At 9.1 and lower you need to match what is negotiated to on the SVRCONN SSLCIPH or use windows policy to force the client side to only use the one cipher you want.

Answer (score 2):

IBM MQ Managed .NET SSL is supported only from v8.0. If you need to use an older version you need to use unmanaged mode. But 7.0.1 is out of support. Use a latest version of the Client.

Comment: Thanks. Poking around the IBM MQ site it looked like version 9.x dropped support for .Net Framework 4.x. Let me try 8.

Comment: IBM MQ v9.x supports .NET Framework and you could use the latest MQ Client Framework libraries with .NET Framework v4.7.2